# i18next parser generates keys '_many' only for me (not my teammates)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, github, internationalization

I have an issue with i18next-parser. Since 2 weeks, during commit, keys `_many` are added in all my translation files. But not for my teammates.

Has anyone faced this kind of problem before?
It's annoying because I have to delete them by hand...

An extract of my configuration (React + typescript) :

```
"i18n-iso-countries": "6.8.0",
"i18n-nationality": "1.1.1",
"i18next": "21.6.7",
"i18next-browser-languagedetector": "6.1.2",
"i18next-fs-backend": "1.1.4",
"i18next-http-backend": "1.3.1",
"i18next-parser": "5.3.0",
"react-i18next": "11.15.3",
"autoprefixer": "9.8.8",
"eslint": "7.32.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.24.2",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.28.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "7.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "1.1.4",
"husky": "7.0.4",
"mkdirp": "1.0.4",
"postcss": "7.0.39",
"prettier": "2.5.1",
"pretty-quick": "3.1.3",
"react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the installed i18next-parser version.
To be sure all are using the same plural suffix rules (v3), set `i18nextOptions` to `{ compatibilityJSON: 'v3' }`
[image]